# Property injection in base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

In the ASP.NET Boilerplate template, there is an `AppServiceBase` that has two properties: `TenantManager` and `UserManager`.

If I need to use these properties, I should do something like:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public TenantManager TenantManager { get; set; }
    public UserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    ctor(TenantManager service1, UserManager service2)
    {
        TenantManager = service1;
        UserManager = service2;
    }
}
```

So I request these two in my derived class `ctor` and pass them to base class:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    ctor(TenantManager service1, UserManager service2)
        : base(service1, service2)
    {
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Use base class properties
        TenantManager.Something();
        UserManager.Something();
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET Core DI, I could do something like:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public TenantManager Service1 => HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<TenantManager>();
    public UserManager Service2 => HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager>();

    ctor()
    {
    }
}
```

And derived classes don't have to request them in `ctor` and pass them to base class:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    ctor(ISpecificService service)
    {
        // I can have other types injected,
        // but TenantManager and UserManager will still be available to use
    }

    public SomeMethod()
    {
        // Use base class properties
        Service1.Something();
        Service2.Something();
    }
}
```

So, how can I achieve something like above in ABP?

I tried:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public TenantManager TenantManager { get; set; }
    public UserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    ctor()
    {
        var t = IocManager.Instance.CreateScope();
        TenantManager = t.Resolve<TenantManager>(); 
        UserManager = t.Resolve<UserManager>();
    }
}
```

However, if I access these properties in derived class, they are already disposed. But according to the documentation, it should live till my class is released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create scope if you're not using the scope in the constructor.

[Property injection pattern](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection#property-injection-pattern) works without resolving in the constructor.

```cs
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public TenantManager TenantManager { get; set; }
    public UserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    ctor()
    {
    }
}
```